# MERN - webpack not building the app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, mern

Recently, I downloaded [mern.io](http://mern.io). The nice thing is they have bundled everything for me. But I am kind of lost. In my last project whenever I changed something on client I could refresh browser and see the changes. With MERN I always see:

> webpack building...
>
> webpack built e9c15d7d435381a63771 in 1043ms

At first it was replacing the code on client. Now, I can't make it to propagate changes any more.

Maybe it's an issue with https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader

What am I missing?

Do I have to **clean** the webpack or caches somehow?

**EDIT**

The config files can be seen here: https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter

The webpack ones are **webpack.config.*.js**

**EDIT 2**

The computer restart helped me but only for the first load of the page. I have found this message in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://0.0.0.0:8000/50d9888579520587227e.hot-update.json

Which led me here: https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/56

Comment: open your application manually in browser at localhost:port specified in your server

Comment: @WitVault What do you mean? I am opening it manually.